# fitting tikz in two column document

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, two-column, tikz-cd

I have the following tikzcd diagrams in my two column document"

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=20,row sep=20]
       P: \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"TPL"] 
        & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/2}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & ... \arrow[r,"TPL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=20,row sep=20]
       D: \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"TUPL"] 
        & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/4}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & ... \arrow[r,"TUPL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

which span further than one column and is overwriting the next column, how can I either make the proceeding column to shift down or superimpose the tikz diagram across the whole page?

Comment: PLease extend your code sniped to compilable small document. We should know your document layout, that we can see how many space is available for your images. Is it an option to have figure over two columns?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

1   You have to interrupt the `multicols` environment at the appropriate place and insert the diagrams.

2   Then increase manually the `column sep` until the diagram reaches  `\textwidth`. (They are to wide to fit in only one column)

3   Finally you add two to horizontal lines to mark the reading flow, otherwise the reader will be confused.

4 Restart the `multicols`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[
bottom=30mm,
top=30mm,
left=25mm,
right=25mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{section 1}
    \lipsum[1-9]        
\section{section 2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=40,row sep=20]
        P: \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"TPL"] 
        & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/2}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & ... \arrow[r,"TPL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=40,row sep=20]
        D: \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"TUPL"] 
        & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/4}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & ... \arrow[r,"TUPL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{multicols}{2}   
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: out6]

A similar result is obtained using the `figure` environment.  Makes the diagrams float, then they will be placed at the top of the page, if that what you wish. It might be a useful trick in some occasions. It will need a caption and a label to make a reference in the text.

The space between the blocks of text serves as a guide to the eye.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=40,row sep=20]
        P: \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"TPL"] 
        & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/2}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & ... \arrow[r,"TPL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G}
    \end{tikzcd}    
\caption{\textbf{First diagram}} \label{fig:D1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=40,row sep=20]
        D: \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/8}{G} \arrow[r,"TUPL"] 
        & \prod_{i=1}^{WS/4}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & ... \arrow[r,"TUPL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G} \arrow[r,"RTL"] & \prod_{i=1}^{WS}{G}
    \end{tikzcd}
    \caption{\textbf{Second diagram}} \label{fig:D2}
\end{figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}   
    As the Diagram \ref{fig:D1} shows, a more deeper approach is needed, like the chosen  in Diagram \ref{fig:D2}.      
    
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
```

Add `\usepackage[figurename= Diagram]{caption}` in the preamble.

[image: ootFloat]